# How to access a method from another running thread in java

Tags: java, multithreading

I am new to Java Threads. What I am trying to do is from ThreadB object gain access to the instance of a current running thread, ThreadA, and call its method called setSomething. 
1) I think I am making harder than it really is
2) I have a null pointer exception so I must be doing something wrong when accessing that method

Here is what I have so far and I have done my due diligence and looked here on StackOverflow for a similar question.

I have a current Thread running in the background:

```
// assume this thread is called by some other application
public class ThreadA implements Runnable{

  private Thread aThread;

  public ThreadA(){
    aThread = new Thread(this);
    aThread.setName("AThread");
    aThread.start();
  }


  @Override
  public void run(){
     while(true){
       // doing something
     }
  }

  public void setSomething(String status){
    // process something
  }
```

}

```
// assume this thread is started by another application
public class ThreadB implements Runnable{

@Override
public void run(){
  passAValue("New");
}

public void passAValue(String status){
   // What I am trying to do is to get the instance of ThreadA and call 
   // its method setSomething but I am probably making it harder on myself
   // not fully understanding threads

   Method[] methods = null;
   // get all current running threads and find the thread i want
   Set<Thread> threadSet = Thread.getAllStackTraces().keySet();
   for(Thread t : threadSet){
     if(t.getName().equals("AThread")){
       methods = t.getClass().getMethods();
     }

   }

   //**How do I access ThreadA's method, setSomething**

}
```

}

Thank you in advance

Allen

Comment: Is there really no way for you to pass the `ThreadA` object _into_ `ThreadB` so you can access it directly.  Doing some reflection hack from the class is _not_ optimal.

Comment: And when you say "started by another application" you don't mean in a different JVM, right?  If it is in another JVM then you are going to have to use RMI or some other inter-processes communication.  Or share a file or something.

Comment: Gray's second comment should be the accepted answer!

Comment: "I am new to X and I do it with reflection." -- This is almost always bound to fail. Reflection is only for those who know how they can avoid it most of the time, and then for the cases where it can't be avoided.

Comment: Thank Gray for your ultra fast response. 

Both threads will be in the same JVM. Essentially, the workflow is ThreadB will be doing some business logic and base on that logic, it will pass some "status" to ThreadA to display an image based on that status (i.e. status can be new, delete, update)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow why do you make things to much complex?! this is not as hard as you think (killing a dragon in a dark castle!)

okay all you need to do is passing the threadA references to threadB! just this. and let me say that when you call a method from thread b, so it runs by thread b, not the class has been hosted.

```
class ThreadA implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        //do something
    }

    public void setSomething() { }
}

class ThreadB implements Runnable {
    private ThreadA aref;

    public ThreadB(ThreadA ref) { aref = ref; }

    public void run() {
        aref.setSomething(); // Calling setSomething() with this thread! (not thread a)
    }
}

class Foo {
    public static void main(String...arg) {
        ThreadA a = new ThreadA();
        new Thread(a).start();

        ThreadB b = new ThreadB(a);
        new Thread(b).start();
    }
}
```

and [here](http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html) a simple threadtutorial

Comment: I know it has been some time over this answer, But I have to say that, when you instantiated ThreadB in main(), you needed to give a as parameter not b. Just pointing out..

Answer (score 1):

When or after you instantiate your ThreadB object, give it a reference to your ThreadA object instance.  Something like:

```
ThreadA a = new ThreadA();
ThreadB b = new ThreadB(a);
```

Then, within the ThreadB code, you can just invoke ThreadA's method by using the reference you have no doubt stored in an instance variable in ThreadB.