# Pausing a thread to get the value of a variable in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

Update - I came across a similar post [How to access a method from another running thread in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19500517/how-to-access-a-method-from-another-running-thread-in-java?answertab=active#tab-top)

However, extracting from the code snippet

```
public void run(){
    aref.setSomething();
    //calling the setSomething() with this thread!!
}
```

But in my case aref.setSomething() never runs because the ThreadA is always busy

Good day, I am trying to write a code in Java that pauses a thread long enough to extract the content of a Map. The thread method operateHosts is called when the thread starts (run) method. 
However I want to be able to pause the thread to allow me read content of the Map and send to a different method.
The problem is the method pauseRun never runs, when I run in debug mode it pauses here and says waiting for XYZ thread.

```
boolean InOperatationFlag = true;

public void run () {

operateHosts(); }

public synchronized void operateHosts() {

while (InOperatationFlag) {
int i = 0;
        for (LRM m : setOfLRMs) {
            System.out.println("Operating Host for thread no" + i);
            m.runControl();
            i++; }

try{ Thread.sleep(2000); }
catch (Exception ex) {

System.out.println ("Busy LRM was interrupted " + ex);
ex.printStackTrace();   }

public void pauseRun() throws InterruptedException {
InOperatationFlag = false; }

public void resumeRun() {
InOperatationFlag = true; }

public List<Map<String, Object>> submitToSchedulerForMigration() throws InterruptedException {
pauseRun();

Set<? extends PowerHost> fakeHostList = new HashSet<PowerHost>();
    fakeHostList = mQueue.keySet();

List<Map<String, Object>> migMap = new LinkedList<Map<String, Object>>();

for (PowerHost ph : fakeHostList) {
        migMap = this.optimizeAllocation(ph, mQueue.get(ph), exHost); }

resumeRun();
    return migMap; }
```

Your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Ughh!  If you want people to help you with your code, you need to pay more attention to code style.  Indent your code properly, follow the identifier conventions,  follow the line break and white-space conventions.

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest use of Atomic types for **anything** related to the thread control/signalling/etc.

```
package test.thread;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class Runner extends Thread{
    private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

    private AtomicBoolean InOperatationFlag = new AtomicBoolean(true);

    public void run () {
        operateHosts(); 
    }

    public void operateHosts() {
        int x = 0;
        while(true) {
            if(InOperatationFlag.get()) {
                int i = 0;
                // commented out for the sake of demo
                /*
                        for (LRM m : setOfLRMs) {
                            System.out.println("Operating Host for thread no" + i);
                            m.runControl();
                            i++; }
                  */
                if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Runner: Running "+x);
            }
            else { 
                if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Runner: Paused "+x);
            }
            x++;
            try{ Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000); }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println ("Runner: Busy LRM was interrupted " + ex);
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public synchronized void pauseRun() throws InterruptedException {
        InOperatationFlag.set(false); 
    }

    public synchronized void resumeRun() {
    InOperatationFlag.set(true);}

    public int submitToSchedulerForMigration() throws InterruptedException {
        //pauseRun(); // commented out for the sake of demo
        int ret = 12345;
        //resumeRun(); // commented out for the sake of demo
        return ret;
    }

    public static void main(String[] argc) throws Exception
    {
        Runner r = new Runner();
        if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Main: New Runner created.");
        r.start();
        if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Main: Runner started.");
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
        if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Main: Slept 5000ms.");
        r.pauseRun();
        if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Main: Pause signal sent.");
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(5000);
        if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Main: Slept 5000ms.");
        System.out.println("Main: Data: "+r.submitToSchedulerForMigration());
        r.resumeRun();
        if(DEBUG) System.out.println("Main: Resume signal sent.");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Main: New Runner created.
Main: Runner started.
Runner: Running 0
Runner: Running 1
Runner: Running 2
Main: Slept 5000ms.
Main: Pause signal sent.
Runner: Paused 3
Runner: Paused 4
Main: Slept 5000ms.
Main: Data: 12345
Main: Resume signal sent.
Runner: Running 5
Runner: Running 6
Runner: Running 7
Runner: Running 8
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thank you very much however assuming there are two threads, that is ThreadA and ThreadB. I can access all methods of ThreadA from ThreadB. The problem I am having is after sending the pause signal from B to A that is a.pauseRun() nothing happens, bcos ThreadA is busy and not respond and I get "waiting for ThreadA" in my debugger. Because operateHosts in a while loop while(true) the pauseRun() sent by B is never attended to

Comment: @shups would it be possible to see the code in question?

Comment: @shups and careful with those synchronized methods -- they block on object level, preventing **all** other synchronized methods in the same object from being executed in parallel until synchronized method is finished.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is the method `pauseRun()` never runs.

It will run when `submitToSchedulerForMigration()` calls it.  But so what?  It sets a flag, and then `submitToSchedulerForMigration()` *immediately* starts to work.  Meanwhile, your `operateHosts()` is still chugging along processing its `setOfLRMs`.

Setting a flag that tells some thread to "stop when you get *here*", won't stop the other thread *until the other thread gets *here**.

One solution would be to set up a means for the stopped thread to communicate back to say when it has reached the stopping point, but a much simpler solution would be to use *mutual exclusion* (a.k.a., *locking*) to prevent the two routines from running at the same time.

```
public final boolean FAIR = true;
public final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock(FAIR);

public synchronized void operateHosts() {

    while (InOperatationFlag) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            int i = 0;
            for (LRM m : setOfLRMs) {
                System.out.println("Operating Host for thread no" + i);
                m.runControl();
                i++;
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}

public List<Map<String, Object>> submitToSchedulerForMigration() throws InterruptedException {
    lock.lock();
    try {

        Set<? extends PowerHost> fakeHostList = new HashSet<PowerHost>();
        fakeHostList = mQueue.keySet();

        List<Map<String, Object>> migMap = new LinkedList<Map<String, Object>>();

        for (PowerHost ph : fakeHostList) {
            migMap = this.optimizeAllocation(ph, mQueue.get(ph), exHost);
        }

    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }

    return migMap;
}
```

NOTE: I could have used `synchronized` blocks here instead of a `Lock` object, but the `ReentrantLock` class implements a useful feature called *fairness*.

Fairness means that when the `submitToSchedulerForMigration()` thread is waiting to acquire the lock, the `operateHosts()` won't be able to release the lock, and then loop around and grab it again before the `submitToSchedulerForMigration()` thread has a chance to wake up.